# Static Method for user Id Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

We are currently using a static property within the application to fetch the userName from siteminder. The problem we are facing is even though every time we access this property we are calling a method inside the get statement to fetch the user name,  the username is getting shared across users. i.e. if user1 has logged in to the application sometimes he gets the value as user2. 
Can someone help with the approach that we should be following. We cannot use session and also there are around 100+ screens from where we are accessing this property.

```
public static string UserID {
        get{
            string userid = "ADMIN";
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteminderAuth"].ToString() == "true")
            {
                // Get a collection of all available HTTP headers from the request
                NameValueCollection coll = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers;

                // Retrieve the userid from the SiteMinder header SM_USER
                userid = coll["SM_USER"].Split('\\')[1];
            }
            else {
                userid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteminderAuth"].ToString();
            }
            return userid;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the method you call do, how does it obtain the username?

Comment: Why can't you use Session?

Comment: Could you share some of the code of that property?

Comment: Sounds like the property getter is not thread safe, please post your code. Sounds like a bad approach generally though.

Comment: Updated the question..

Comment: You still have not answered why you can't use Session. Please answer that question.

Comment: @mason not allowed to use session..

Comment: @AmitAgarwal That still doesn't answer my question. Session is the perfect tool for this task. Anything you could do to solve this problem would be a reinvention of Session anyways.